# OpenNMS 20.0.0 Using the Dashboard role

Tags: opennms

I am having issues with the Dashboard Role.  In the OpenNMS guide I have setup the example stated in the guide as follows:

3.2.1. Using the Dashboard role
The following example illustrates how this Dashboard role can be used. For instance the user drv4doe is assigned the dashboard role. So, when logging in as drv4doe, the user is taking directly to the Dashboard page and is presented with a custom Dashboard based on the drv4doe Surveillance View definition.

When I setup user and group following the 3 steps I am getting a error "Access denied.  You do not have permission to access this page."

Logged in as admin I see the drv4doe dashboard view.  This appears to be a permissions issue as it appears that OpenNMS is not permitting those that have the Dashboard role to access the Dashboard.

I can not located any logs that explain the access denied message so I can determine where to look to fix this.

Answer (score 1):

I tried to reproduce your problem and can confirm this issue still exists in Horizon 22.0.0. We have a bug report in our issue tracker https://issues.opennms.org/browse/NMS-9738 and will investigate how to fix and fix the problem. The role "ROLE_DASHBOARD" ensures the user is getting a different Dashboard start page. You should be able to configure the dashboards when you assign the ROLE_USER.

If you create a surveillance view with the same name of the associated group or the user's login name, he should get this view as default.

Just as a note, with the assigned role ROLE_USER he will be able to navigate all other parts of the Web UI as well.